# How do I put export inside shell script for including oracle libs

Tags: python, bash, export, cx-oracle

I have a shell script like below

```
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$LD_LBRARY_PATH

python my_python.py
```

It throws below error when triggered.

```
import cx_Oracle
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

If I run the exports in the command line and run the `python my_python.py` in the command line it works.

What am I missing when I tried to put them in the script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exports are not related to the error you are getting - you would get an error from cx_Oracle itself if they were the problem.  Instead, Python can't even find cx_Oracle to load.

Make sure both environments are running the same Python binary.  If you installed cx_Oracle with `pip install cx_Oracle --user` then also make sure you are running the script as the same user.

Unrelated to the problem: this line is wrong `export PATH=$PATH:$LD_LBRARY_PATH`. It is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even when I ran as the same user ( I was in the same session when I tried command line vs scripts) script was throwing. I have changed to '/usr/bin/python3.8 my_python.py' in the script -  which worked. So, when I ran as shell script, somehow, was referring to old version (which didn't have cx_Oracle). So, like you mentioned, it is not export issue, rather shell referring to wrong version of Python.